# How to debug event in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, events

I'm new to flex, and using a small open-source UI library [ReCoral](https://github.com/xiaotie/RedCoral). In my test, I use its `Application` class as the root of mxml, and which has a click handler.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<common:Application
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:common="geb.common.*" width="500" height="500"
    xmlns:controls="geb.controls.*"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    click="hello()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function hello(): void {
                trace("world");
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <controls:Label text="Click Me" height="100" width="100" click="hello()" />
</common:Application>
```

You can see the code is quite simple.

But when I click the Label, or the Application, the `hello()` method seems never invoked. I tried to add a breakpoint on the `trace("world")` line in debug mode, it had never been triggered.

Since the author is quite busy, and I'm new to flex, I don't know how to debug this problem.

1. Is there any way to listen any click event, and log the information?
2. Is there any useful document I should read?

Comment: Not familiar with RedCoral, but the syntax you are using to add the listeners and everything else you are doing seems correct.  Try swapping out the RedCoral components (`<common:Application />` and `<controls:Label />`) with the standard Flex components (`<s:Application />` and `<s:Label />`). Do the listeners work w/the Flex components?

Comment: After reading some of RedCoral's source code, I found it set `mouseEnabled` to `false`, so I have to set it to true in `Label`

Comment: And thank you very much. I think I should delete this question soon

Comment: Rather than delete it, maybe you can add your answer ... someone else may benefit from it. Setting `mouseEnabled=false` is a good optimization when you never expect to use mouse events, but will probably catch other users of RedCoral by surprise too.

Comment: I'm unclear why this question is Flex related if you're using an alternate UI Library...

Comment: I'm new to flex. Please modify the tags if you think it's improper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason, that `Label` in RedCoral set `mouseEnabled` to `false` in `inited` method:

```
override protected function init():void
{
    super.init();
    mouseEnabled = false;
    mouseChildren = false;
}
```

See: https://github.com/xiaotie/RedCoral/blob/master/src/geb/controls/Label.as#L112

So we should enable it:

```
<controls:Label text="Click Me" height="100" width="100" click="hello()" mouseEnabled="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You need to add the event type

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<common:Application
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:common="geb.common.*" width="500" height="500"
xmlns:controls="geb.controls.*"
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
click="hello()">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function hello(event:MouseEvent): void {
            trace("world");
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<controls:Label text="Click Me" height="100" width="100" click="hello(event)" />
</common:Application>
```